# Angular CLI component calling external javascript function

Tags: angular-cli

Trying to call an external javascript function from within an angular CLI component

the below js code is on the same page as my angular

```
  <script>
    var _ChartingCommon = {
         DrawChart: function( $ele, opts ) {
         . . .
    }
  </script>
```

in my component.ts file i have

```
 declare var _ChartingCommon: any; 

 ngOnInit(): void {
     _ChartingCommon.DrawGauge(res, "EstGaugeContainer", null, override);
 }
```

the error is:  _ChartingCommon is not defined

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the function via the `window` object. But typescript did not know about your variable so you have to make a cast to `any` before.

```
(<any>window)._ChartingCommon.DrawChart(res, "EstGaugeContainer", null, override);
```